# 2 Variable outcomes cant have two?

Tags: javascript

I have:

```
var outcome = $('#outcome') ;
```

With one outcome "#outcome" but i want to have two outcomes

i have tried

```
var outcome = $('#outcome #outcome2') ;
```

Comment: Removed the Java tag from the question ;-) --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Separate the selectors with a comma:

```
var outcome = $('#outcome, #outcome2');
```

What you currently have is looking for an element matching `#outcome2` that is a descendant of an element matching `#outcome`.

This is documented under "[multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)" in the jQuery API. As noted on that page, an alternative is to use the [`add`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method (but I would definitely recommend sticking with the multiple selector in this case):

```
var outcome = $('#outcome').add('#outcome2');
```